# Postgres autovacuum doesn't free disk space

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

I have a DB where in one table i have over 8 million inserts every day (recordings are distributed over time, about 90-100 per second).

And every day I delete all records over 7 days old, but disk space for table doesn't stop growing.

Autovacuum is "on" with default configuration. Delete query is executed in 2:55 the night. Last autovacuum for table is about 3 hours later 6:32 and no second run.

Why disk space every day is about 1gb more?

I now autovacuum don't free disk space immediately, but I can use the deleted rows for new inserts.

Right now, it seems like I'm deleting the records but I do not use the free space for new ones and the table keeps growing.

Every day after deleting the old records, about 50 million rows remain in the table, and  they are almost the same as to the stored size.

Is it possible that Postgres wants to reach a certain size for the table it thinks it can manipulate without problems? I'm not trying this because there is not as much free space, and when the space is full  I `TRUNCATE` the table.

Answer (score 0):

You mean table storage size and not memory right?

First, some general things you should check to determine the problem:

Set `log_autovacuum_min_duration` to something other than -1 and see if messages are generated.

Watch for autovacuum processes in `pg_stat_activity`. Are there any running on your problem table?

Examine the output of

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_user_tables
WHERE relname = 'prablemtable';
```

What is `n_live_tup` and `n_dead_tup`?
What is `autovacuum_count` and `last_autovacuum`?

My suspicion is that autovacuum is running, but cannot do its job, because [one of these three things prevents it from cleaning up](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/reasons-why-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows/):

- Long running transactions in state `idle in transaction`.
- Stale [replication slots](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-replication-slots.html).
- Orphaned [prepared transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-prepared-xacts.html).